# TypeError: unorderable types: function() > int()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev

I don't know why in my `if statements` in the `for loops` it considers them unorderable types to make a comparison with. The exact error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Eclipse/Week6/src/numbers.py", line 44, in <module>
    myDict = {'AvgPositive':posNumAvg(numInput), 'AvgNonPos':nonPosAvg(numInput),                'AvgAllNum':allNumAvg(numInput)}     
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Eclipse/Week6/src/numbers.py", line 30, in posNumAvg
    if num > 0:
TypeError: unorderable types: function() > int()
```

And my code is as follows:

```
#While loop function for user input
def numInput():
    numbers = []

    while True:
        num = int(input('Enter a number (-9999 to end):'))
        if num == -9999:
            break
        numbers.append(num)
    return numbers

#Average of all numbers function
def allNumAvg(numList):
    return sum(numList) / len(numList)


#Average of all positive numbers function
def posNumAvg(numList):
    for num in [numList]:
        if num > 0:
            posNum = sum(num)
            posLen = len(num)
    return posNum / posLen

#Avg of all negative numbers function
def nonPosAvg(numList):
    for num in [numList]:
        if num < 0:
            negNum = sum(num)
            negLen = len(num)
    return negNum / negLen

#Creates Dictionary
myDict = {'AvgPositive':posNumAvg(numInput), 'AvgNonPos':nonPosAvg(numInput), 'AvgAllNum':allNumAvg(numInput)}   

#Prints List
print ('The list of of all numbers entered is\n', numInput(),'\n')

#Prints Dictionary
print ('The dictionary with averages is\n', myDict)
```

I know there is some basic concept I'm missing.

Comment: `for num in [numList]` does not do what you think it does. `[numList]` builds a 1-element list whose only element is `numList`, and then the loop performs 1 iteration with `num=numList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numInput` is a function, but you aren't calling it when you pass it to `posNumAvg` when defining `myDict` here:

```
posNumAvg(numInput)
```

That function is passed to `posNumAvg` as local variable `numList`, then is `num`, then is compared against `0`, always referencing the function. Functions and numbers can't be compared, and that's the error you're seeing.

You probably just need to call the function, like this:

```
posNumAvg(numInput())
```

Comment: Ah I see, the reason it's giving me that error is because I'm trying to compare a function to a number. I tried adding the parentheses to the dictionary where I call it, but I'm still getting the error. Any other suggestion to make the comparison? Or perhaps an entirely different way to attack it? Thanks!